# URL rewriting with ISAPI Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting

I am trying to create a filter system for products and keep the URL's friendly, i am using a map file for the filter params and the following re-write code.

The url could contain, one param or 10 params and will be bulit like so

```
Start URL: www.domain.com/climbing-frames/
First Param: www.domain.com/climbing-frames_rockwall/
Second Param: www.domain.com/climbing frames_rockwall_rope-ladder/
```

And so on.....

The rewrite rule so far

```
 RewriteMap features txt:features.txt
    RewriteCond ${features:$1|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
    RewriteRule ^climbing-frames(?:_([^/]+))(?:_([^/]+))(?:_([^/]+))(?:_([^/]+))/ /get-features.cfm?(?1(param1=${features:$1|0}))(?2(,${features:$2|0}))(?3(,${features:$3|0}))(?4(,${features:$4|0}))
```

This works if 4 prams are entered but not if only two params are entered. This is driving me crazy!

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Jason

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close - there might be a looping approach that would be better, but I do tend to go with the way you're going.

I see how you're doing the non-capturing underscore, then capturing the next characters. Instead of looking for not-slash, look for not-underscore. With the not-slash, it's going to grab the whole thing in the first group. That is, look for underscore-not-underscore.

Then (getting to the real fix), each section needs to be optional - the rule above is requiring the four sections. So add a ? to the end of each one, as:

```
RewriteRule ^climbing-frames(?:_([^_]+))(?:_([^_]+))?(?:_([^_]+))?(?:_([^_]+))?/
```

I left the first group required, since it practically should be there, and the RewriteCond is checking for it anyway.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your answer, I didn't think anyone got to see the question, I will try this upon my return today!!! I did have a work around in place using a single rewrite for every option!!! Very time consuming and possibly long processing times!

Comment: Hi Goodeye
This didn't work for me, I could get the first rewrite to work I.e. param one but not the rest?

Comment: I use regular-expressions.info's RegexBuddy application, but I also just tried it on regexlib.com. It worked, but I had to be careful of the slash in front (or not), and in the two-param example above, there's a missing hyphen after climbing. Maybe it's just that sort of thing?